# window.ethereum.addListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ethereum, blockchain

I have this listener:

```
if (window.ethereum) {
  window.ethereum.addListener('accountsChanged', async () => {
    await doSomething();
  });
}
```

However it seems like some users cause this issue: `window.ethereum.addListener is not a function`

Any ideas why? It seems random as I cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 2):

there is no `addListener` in [ethereum api](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#table-of-contents)

ethereum emits `accountChanged` event. and you can listen to it. you should be listening on top layer of your application. Fore example in a provider

```
useEffect(() => {
  // define handleAccountsChanged
  ethereum?.on("accountsChanged", handleAccountsChanged);
  return () => {
    ethereum?.removeListener("accountsChanged", handleAccountsChanged);
  };
```

Comment: addListener does work though, it triggers my function when an account changes

Comment: Error message says “addListener is not a function” but you say “addListener does work though”. Very interesting!